# How to declare that a Typescript function returns the type of a named property?

Tags: typescript

I want to input the name of an interface property, and return something which has the type of that property. Is that possible? For example:

```
interface FooInterface {
  x: number;
  y: string;
}

function fooFunction(data: FooInterface, name: keyof FooInterface) {
  return data[name];
}

let fooVar = fooFunction({ x: 123, y: "hello" }, "x"); // <- Is it possible to make this smart enough to understand that fooVar is now a number?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just want to make `fooFunction()` a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) with a type parameter `K` that is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof FooInterface`.  The `name` parameter would be of this generic type `K`:

```
function fooFunction<K extends keyof FooInterface>(data: FooInterface, name: K) {
    return data[name];
}
```

Now  the compiler infers that `data[name]` returns a generic [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `FooInterface[K]` instead of `string | number`.

When you call `fooFunction()`, the compiler will infer `K` from the `name` parameter you pass in:

```
let fooVar = fooFunction({ x: 123, y: "hello" }, "x");
// function fooFunction<"x">(data: FooInterface, name: "x"): number
```

Since `K` is specified with `"x"`, then the function returns `FooInterface["x"]` which is `number`.  And so `fooVar` is known to be a `number`:

```
// let fooVar: number
fooVar.toFixed(2); // okay no compiler error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0ElzXk5AbwChkzkAPALmRAFcBbAI2gG5TyBPGgZzClABzdgF9ixGHRAIwwdCGQxMqKTLkgAPAGlkECpBAATHsgDWETuhhpMOSLEQQAfAApDcMHBoZsuB0gAaWjgGCBotAEoiDjIoCDA6KAV3TwBtEBCIAF1RcQAbeMVMADU4KGQAXiL0FWlZeRdCShoARgAmAGYg7mQAIgALCDy89F7kESDeil6I9gB6OcVVeoUlGuX1DSne1xSvG197fAggjNCabYiaemZoYgXkArBq0qhrxhYoCRKygDowGrACgQQwuNqzZAPdCmOCcWjoZAIdAMAAOwAK5WgUHQUCAA)